# History of rule changes in tennis

Tags: rules, tennis, history, atp

What were the changes in professional tennis' rules (e.g., the doubles reforms of 2006) in the currrent century? Links to the ATP rulebooks in which those rules are stated might suffice as an acceptable answer. ATP's website only has the [current year rulebook](http://www.atpworldtour.com/Corporate/Rulebook.aspx).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not provide for reference requests.

Comment: get in touch with ATP directly

Comment: @Nij I added additional tags to address your concern, the question is asking what are the changes in the rules of professional tennis in recent years, which should fit the site format. The ATP rulebooks provide just an easier way to obtain the answer.

Comment: That may be why you're asking, but it's not what you're asking.

Comment: @Nij The question wording has changed to address your last comment.

Comment: So the accepted answer now doesn't answer at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research, and with the help of the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/), I was able to compile a list of pdf's for most of the rulebooks since 2001.

To understand where we're getting these rulebooks from, we must first dive into the history of the ATP's websites, with respective rulebooks. The chronology of the internet presence of what is currently the "[ATP World Tour](http://www.atpworldtour.com/)" goes a little something like this:

> ***Chronology of "ATP World Tour" Website***
>
> 1995 - "The ATP Tour launches its first ATP website, ATP Online..." <sup>1</sup>
>   Unfortunately, not much is known about this site, and it doesn't
>   appear in any search results I performed. As a result, no rulebooks
>   from this time period have been provided
>
> 2001 - "A newly launched website, ATPtennis.com, highlights the new tournament structure. ATP Properties forms, instigating a more commercial focus and new marketing, licensing and broadcasting opportunities." <sup>2</sup>
>   Rulebooks referenced from 2001 and up to 2008 will be from this site and not the current ATP World Tour site.
>
> 2008 to 2018 - The ATP World Tour website as we know it today first came into existence in 2008 and has largely kept the same form even into today. The majority of rulebooks come from this site's archives.

Without further adieu, here are the rulebooks up until 2001:

> ***ATP World Tour Rulebooks "2001-2017"***
>
> [2017 ATP World Tour Rulebook](http://www.atpworldtour.com/-/media/files/rulebook/2017/2017-atp-rulebook)
>
> [2016 ATP World Tour Rulebook](http://www.atpworldtour.com/~/media/files/rulebook/2016/2016-atp-rulebook_8jan16.pdf)
>
> [2015 ATP World Tour Rulebook](http://www.atpworldtour.com/~/media/files/rulebook/2015/2015-atp-rulebook_sept15.pdf)
>
> [2014 ATP World Tour Rulebook](https://filebin.ca/3qQNStvhvsvF/2014_ATP_Rulebook.pdf)
>
> [2013 ATP World Tour Rulebook](http://assets.usta.com/assets/1/15/2012_ATP_Rulebook.pdf)
>
> [2012 ATP World Tour Rulebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20120619011221/http://www.atpworldtour.com:80/Corporate/Rulebook.aspx)
>   : Click on "rulebook" and download the file (only way to access)
>
> [2011 ATP World Tour Rulebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20110522132417/http://www.atpworldtour.com/Corporate/Rulebook.aspx)
>   : Click on "rulebook" and download the file (only way to access)
>
> [2010 ATP World Tour Rulebook](http://assets.usta.com/assets/1/USTA_Import/images/sitecore_ustasections/USTA/Document%20Assets/2010_ATP_Rulebook.pdf)
>
> [2009 ATP World Tour Rulebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20090622172759/http://www.atpworldtour.com:80/Corporate/Rulebook.aspx)
>   : The page states the rule changes at the bottom from 2008 for the 2009
>   season, which is what OP is looking for anyway
>
> [2008 ATP World Tour Rulebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20081226135721/http://www.atpworldtour.com:80/en/aboutatp/plans.asp)
>   : The "rulebook" link is unfortunately inaccessible, but I will update
>   my answer if I am able to find the 2008 edition
>
> [2007 ATP World Tour Rulebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20070106221634/http://www.atptennis.com:80/1/en/home/)
>   : The "rulebook" link is unfortunately inaccessible, but I will update
>   my answer if I am able to find the 2007 edition
>
> [2006 ATP World Tour Rulebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20051217001930/http://www.atptennis.com:80/en/common/TrackIt.asp?file=/en/players/ATP_Rulebook.pdf)
>
> [2005 ATP World Tour Rulebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20050504115510/http://www.atptennis.com:80/en/common/TrackIt.asp?file=/en/players/ATP_Rulebook_2005.pdf)
>
> [2004 ATP World Tour Rulebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20040525200554/http://www.atptennis.com:80/en/common/TrackIt.asp?file=/en/players/ATP_Rulebook_2004.pdf)
>
> [2003 ATP World Tour Rulebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20030424013000/http://www.atptennis.com:80/en/common/TrackIt.asp?file=/en/players/ATP_Rulebook_2003.pdf)
>
> [2002 ATP World Tour Rulebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20030325150502/http://www.atptennis.com:80/en/players/ATP_Rulebook_2002.pdf)
>
> Here are the specific changes from the [2002 to 2003 rulebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20030424041027/http://www.atptennis.com:80/en/common/TrackIt.asp?file=/en/players/rulebook_ammendments.pdf)
>
> [2001 ATP World Tour Rulebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20010302164849/http://www.atptennis.com:80/en/insidetheatp/column/)*
>   : I was unable to find the rulebook on the site, and do not believe it
>   exists anywhere online

A special thank you to [Martin Sleziak](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8297/martin-sleziak) who helped provide the 2010 and 2014 editions.

> Sources:
>
> 1. https://web.archive.org/web/20081226135656/http://www.atpworldtour.com:80/en/aboutatp/history.asp
> 2. http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/corporate/history